# JQuery Flot: clear graph

Tags: jquery, graph, flot

Is there a recommended way to clear a jQuery Flot graph? I couldn't find anything the in the API reference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By "clear" do you mean "nuke the entire graph," or just clear the data?

To nuke the entire graph: `$('#canvas_id').empty();`

To clear the data, just call the usual `$.plot(placeholder, data, options);` where data is empty.

Comment: is there any significance with respect to nuking...?

Comment: What is the right way to make sure all event handlers are cleaned up?

Comment: @thecountofzero any sane browser (so, exclude old versions of IE) should take care of this for you. Are you seeing evidence to the contrary?

Comment: This creates generates an error when attempting with the pie plugin.

Comment: @JoshBuchea for what it's worth, this answer is well over eight years old, which is pretty much an eternity in Javascript years.

Comment: @MattBall an eternity indeed. Believe it or not I'm working at a startup that uses Flot charts in production today, so the information is still relevant to some!

Answer (score 1):

in my case just clearing container won't help, some flot bindings stil working.

```
var plot = $.plot(placeholder, data, options);
// some other code
//to completely remove flot chart call
plot.destroy(); // remove graph and all bindings
```

to clear only graph use Matt Ball ansver.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to destroy! Also helpful to note that destroy will internally call shutdown and remove any registered event handlers.